# Pattern to map JPA Objects to DTO for Conversion to JSON

Tags: json, design-patterns, jpa, dto

I have a somewhat philosophical question relating to mapping JPA Objects to JSON Strings.  Of course there is no necessity for the source object to be a persistent object - it is just that that is my situation.

I have a collection of objects that are managed by Eclipse Link.  I need to turn some of these objects into JSON Strings, however the mapping is not one-to-one.  I am convinced that the conversion should be loosely coupled so as to isolate the JSON objects from changes in the underlying entities.

I am planning to have the JPA entity as such:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AbnormalFlags")
public class AbnormalFlag  implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Code", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "Description", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String description;

// Getters and setters

}
```

and the equivalent object to be converted to JSON

```
public class AbnormalFlagDTO  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String code;
    private String description;
    private Boolean disabled;

// Getters and setters

}
```

Is there an elegant pattern or methodology I can use to facilitate this process for several types of objects.

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer: no, and  also you should generally extend DTOs with care (when reusing existing DTOs). But you could use a `Map<String, Object>` as a DTO (if you do not use the same DTO to read the data back). Besides you could create an [APT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html) (annotation processor tool) that generates the code for DTOs from your entities and then you simply modify them.

Comment: Thank you for you=r comments.  By way of completness, I have found that both ModelMapper and Dozer will solve my problem

Comment: Thank you for your comment! ModelMapper is definitely better than a Map, but probably you won't have a good solution for reading the data (when e.g you get only the customerId, and you have to find it in DB).

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) as you will most probably also want to keep an eye on the performance of the query used for fetching the data.

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface defined models. The idea is that you define your target structure the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model. Since the attribute name is used as default mapping, you mostly don't need explicit mappings as 80% of the use cases is to have DTOs that are a subset of the entity model.

A mapping for your model could look as simple as the following

```
@EntityView(AbnormalFlag.class)
interface AbnormalFlagDTO extends Serializable {
  String getCode();
  String getDescription();
  Boolean getDisabled();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`AbnormalFlagDTO dto = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, AbnormalFlagDTO.class, id);`

The serialization of the entity view to JSON will work as expected. If you also want to deserialize objects, you will have to construct the object first and also add setters to the interface.

Comment: Thank you for this follow up